# Should a POST Request ever be more than 60KB?

Tags: http, post, tcp

The question is pretty self explanatory.

I know GET and all the other HTTP methods should never be very long, but what's the most a POST will ever realistically be? What cap do the three main browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) put on POSTs?

Comment: Optimize?  You targeting a 16-bit processor?

Comment: The POST can be whatever size the client needs to send, within the server's imposed size cap.  It really depends on what is being posted in the first place, and what the server Is willing to accept.  there is not enough information here to answer that one way or the other.

Comment: I'm building a rather large program, and I want it to have as small a footprint as possible. I'm just in the habit of being conservative. And besides, I'd like to know what to expect regardless of what data type I end up using.

Comment: Optimizing for space means compromising speed:(

Answer (score 1):

Lots of POST will be more than 60k. Typical uploads of pictures can be about a megabyte and since it is possible to upload multiple files within the same request it can be often be more. In principle there is no limitation so you could also upload ISO images (several gigabytes) etc.

Of course it might be that in your specific use case (like a HTML form) the payload is smaller then 60k, but this is then specific to your application.

Comment: And the client won't attempt to break up such a gigantic (several GBs) POST into partial smaller ones?

Comment: @RogueCSDev: not necessarily. Like I said, there is no limitation from the protocol side. But if course it makes sense to enforce an limitation on the application side if you don't expect such large payloads in your application.